# Why does VSCode show 'problems' which do not exist?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode with the python extension. The 'problems' tab as well as the indicators on the 'explorer' tab and the red underline in the code view itself all show there to be an error, even though the error isn't real.

After importing `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`, the code uses `plt.cm.RdBu`. VSCode is presenting the error that `matplotlib.cm` has no member `RdBu`.

There are two issues here:

- Unless I'm just mistaken, `plt.cm.RdBu` ought to be equivalent to `matplotlib.pyplot.cm.RdBu`, not `matplotlib.cm.RdBu`. It seems to be interpreting that incorrectly.
- But regardless of that, both `cm` and `pyplot.cm` actually do have an attribute called `RdBu`, both of which I was able to pull up information for using `help()`. The code runs perfectly and python throws no errors.

Why is VSCode telling me this is an error when it isn't? Is this just a bug or could it be a misconfiguration?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python on your machine? Similar import problems has happened to me before because VS Code was configured by default to use a different Python version than the one I use to run the code. Is the Python version at the bottom-left corner the same as the one you get with `python3 --version`?

Comment: `python3 --version` turns up nothing. `python --version` returned 3.8.3, which is the same as VSCode is using (as displayed in the bottom left). Besides, I'm running the code within VSCode, so it should be using the same version regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to fix this issue. The reason that VS Code, or more specifically, the linter used by the Python extension isn't picking up `matplotlib.pyplot.cm.RdBu`, or any other colormaps defined in `cm` is because they're defined *dynamically*. If you try looking inside `cm.py`, you'll only find this:

```py
cmap_d = _gen_cmap_d()
locals().update(cmap_d)
```

Essentially, instead of being statically defined like `RdBu = ...`, these colormaps are defined dynamically by being injected into the module's global namespace *at runtime*. Even though this works fine when you run it, unfortunately it means that there's no way for the linter to know that names such as `RdBu` exist in the namespace until runtime. And as most linters such as `pylint` and `flake8` are static code analysis tools that never actually execute the code, it's impossible for them to detect the existence of these colormaps.